# Write a string of several lines to a file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
Open "output.txt" For Output As #1
s = "abc" & chr(10) & "def"
Msgbox s
print #1, s
```

When I run this code, the `Msgbox` does print 2 lines. However, in `output.txt`, `abcdef` is printed.

Does anyone know how to output a string of several lines to a file?

Comment: Instead of `Chr(10)` try `vbCrLf`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For it to appear on separate lines within a text file you will need `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` or `vbCrLf` or if you're in excel vba `vbNewLine`. All of which will provide the needed carriage return `Chr(13)` and line feed `Chr(10)` characters to produce a line break.

Examples (All 3 Produce The Same Result):

```
"First Line" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Second Line"
"First Line" & vbCrLf & "Second Line"
"First Line" & vbNewLine & "Second Line"
```

Output:

```
"First Line"
"Second Line"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the TextStream object (via FileSystemObject's CreateTextFile method) instead.  This will give you the ability to separate lines out as needed.

For example, your situation would instead be:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject ' Declare a FileSystemObject.
Set fso = New FileSystemObject ' Create a FileSystemObject.
Dim stream As TextStream ' Declare a TextStream.

Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\output.txt", True)
stream.WriteLine "abc"
stream.WriteLine "def"
stream.Close
```

MSDN has this covered: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264514.aspx

Comment: Sorry, are you sure `stream.writeLine "abc" & chr(10) & "def"` prints 2 lines?

Comment: No, your method does not print two lines.  That's why I recommended the WriteLine method instead.  It would write a separate line per each string given to each instance of the method.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:
Add extra string instead of the line breaker. For example the value of my cell is "testing#BR#jump#BR#lines" Then I used a split function and use a for loop to write line by line into the file:

```
For xrow = 2 To 10
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test\History_" & Cells(xrow , 1) & ".txt")
    matLines = Split(Cells(xrow, 2), "#BR#")
    For line = 0 To UBound(matLines)
        oFile.WriteLine matLines(line)
    Next line
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
Next xrow
```

The result was the file line by line.